# Arduino Uno COM issue + Braccio qu

Tags: arduino-uno

hey guys so i get this error when plugging in my arduino and not sure why:

> Blockquote
>
> Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"
>
> Sketch uses 930 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256
>   bytes. Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving
>   2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
>   **avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM5": The system cannot find the file specified.**
>
> Problem uploading to board.  See
>   http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
>
> This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
>   during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.

How can i solve it? It used to work and not sure what's happened... also does anyone know if the Braccio robotic arm can be connected to arduino via just the arduino/usb cable alone? Because when i connect the braccio shield v4 to both th arduino(and to laptop) and to the wall, it actually causes my laptop to switch off ??

Comment: it appears that you are asking three different questions .... please ask only one question per post

Comment: the error is indicating serial port COM5 on your computer is unavailable. (windows treats a serial port like a 'file' on the programming level, hence the confusing message). This could be a hardware issue or a driver issue. You'll have to troubleshoot that first.